# Using BufferedWriter to get input from the user and write it to a file

Tags: java, user-input, bufferedwriter

I just started using Java, so sorry if I ask some very simple questions. I basically have to get the user to continuously integers, and once they enter a negative number, the loop will exit. The code I have written so far does not seem to be able to write the input I get from the user to the file I created, morescores. When I try opening the file or calling it from the main method, it's blank. I've tried searching it up on google, youtube, and on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working. I"ll appreciate any help I can get :)

```
package bufferedreader;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BufferedReader {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   writeToFile("morescores");
   processFile("morescores");      
}


public static void writeToFile (String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("morescores.txt"));
    int score = 1;            
   while (true) {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
       score = reader.nextInt();
        if (score < 0) { 
            break;
       } else {
          outputWriter.write(score);
          outputWriter.newLine();           
    }      
    }
   outputWriter.flush();
   outputWriter.close();
}

public static void processFile2 (String filename) throws IOException {
    java.io.BufferedReader inputReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream ("morescores.txt")));
    String line;
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println (line);
    }
    inputReader.close();
}

}
```

UPDATE: I fixed the problem haha turns out I was trying to print an integer when it could only be a string.  I actually have a followup question, I also need to find the average of all the numbers the user inputs. How would I do that? How can I write a code so that the program knows how many times the user inputs a value I actually have a followup question, I also need to find the average of all the numbers the user inputs. How would I do that? How can I write a code so that the program knows how many times the user inputs a value

Comment: Note that your methods aren't using the `filename` parameter at all .

Comment: `outputWriter.write(score + "\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `int` to a String before writing to your file so

```
outputWriter.write(score);
```

would be:

```
outputWriter.write(String.valueOf(score));
```

if you are wondering why it has to be converted first look at the doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(int)

you'll see that it doesn't write the `int` but the character represented by the `int`

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe my mistake was so simple, haha. I actually have a followup question, I also need to find the average of all the numbers the user inputs. How would I do that? How can I write a code so that the program knows how many times the user inputs a value?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass **int** value to the **write** method of **BufferedWriter** class, then it will be consider as **character** instead of number, therefore with the current code you have written whatever positive number you are providing will get converted to valid char value and then it will be written into the file.
In order to achieve what you are asking for you need to convert your int value to string before writing it to file and to do that you can use any of the below methods :

```
String.valueOf(score)  
Integer.toString(score)
```